# Предложение о переименовании метки `language-lawyer`

Tags: предложение, переименование-метки

Мне кажется, что упомянутой в заголовке метке можно дать русскоязычное название, например [знаток-языка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d0%ba-%d1%8f%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%ba%d0%b0), [нюансы-языка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bd%d1%8e%d0%b0%d0%bd%d1%81%d1%8b-%d1%8f%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%ba%d0%b0) или [языковые-тонкости](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%8f%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8).

Предлагаю обсудить возможные варианты.

Всё таки на русском stackoverflow, имхо, в приоритете должны быть именно русскоязычные метки.

Comment: Вы не поняли назначение метки. Под этой меткой собираются вопросы с просьбами разобраться в сложных формальных спецификациях, то есть объяснить ситуацию де-юре (по спецификации), а не де-факто (по реализации). В этой метке особенно популярны мозговыносящие спецификации на сотни страниц и десятки компиляторов с несовместмыми конструкциями — конкурс, в котором плюсы выигрывают с большим отрывом. P. S. Вы можете оформлять метки в виде меток с помощью `[tag:foo]`.

Comment: @Discord Единственное, чего я не понял, почему Вы решили, что предложенные мною метки не подходят под Ваше описание.

Comment: Ваши формулировки не акцентируют внимание на преобладании де-юре над де-факто. Другими словами, все три варианта в равной мере могут относиться как к спецификации, так и к реализации.

Comment: @Discord Возможно Вы правы, но в моем понимании [tag:языковые-тонкости] подразумевает именно вопросы спецификации, т.е. стандарта. Для вопросов непосредственно по деталям реализации я бы предложил например [tag:тонкости-реализации]. Ну или явное упоминание того или иного компилятора. В любом случае, вопрос в первую очередь о переводе метке на русский язык.